# Retrieve a small form and place it on an ASP.NET WebForm using AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax, webforms

I'm looking to integrate a small form into my ASP.NET page that pops up like a modal popup but is **not loaded until the window pops up.**

Basically, here are the steps:

1. Have a pre-existing ASP.NET form.
2. User clicks a button.
3. A modal popup pops up (using jQuery - the popup starts as a div with style set to display: none)
4. The popup is shown and a "please wait" spinning circle thing spins while...
5. An async call is made to the server asking for a simple form.

The simple form will have a textbox and a button.  The controls are ASP.NET controls (obviously they are run at the server and then sent back to the browser in readable HTML) and, after typing information into the textbox, you push the ASP.NET button and it posts back, calls the Button1_Click event and sends the contents of the textbox to the server.

My question is, can this be done without using ASP.NET AJAX?  Can it be done using jQuery or an XMLHTTPRequest, for instance, to perform a GET on another .aspx page or a web service, and render the contents of that page inside the modal popup?

Answer (score 0):

ajax is `XMLHTTPRequest` it only makes your life easier... and the answer is yes it can be done

here is a good post https://stackoverflow.com/a/4657324/413670