# Handling JSON data in Codeigniter Controller

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I have a problem to send the JSON data from JQuery with GET request. This is my JQuery to send the data with GET.

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://example.com/share/new?data=" + JSON.stringify({"id": "1", "type": "new", "data": "testabcd"});
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
```

This is in my Controller file.

```
    public function share()
    {
        header('Content-type: application/json');

        $Data = json_decode($_GET["data"]);

        $data_share = array(
            'id' => $Data['id'],
            'type' => $Data['type'],
            'data' => $Data['data']);

        $this->db->insert('mytable', $data_share);

        return "200";
    }
```

The problem is nothing grab in the Controller and the insert query doesn't insert anything. How to fix this problem ? Maybe I do something wrong in my code ? Thank you before.

Comment: Does `$Data` have value?

Comment: @aldrin27 How to see `$Data` has a value or not ?

Comment: `print_r($Data); exit;` below `$Data`

Comment: Nothing happen after I add `print_r` @aldrin27

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you send json data to php its in doesn't come in `$_POST` or `$_GET` its in `php://input` strem;

the ajax request u send ws not jQuery its core js, which is good but its quite unflexible and tends to break in different browser. i just used the jQuery version of the ajax which is very flexible and cross-browser as well.

try this :
JS:

```
$.ajax({
      method:'POST',
      contentType:'application/json',
      url:'http://example.com/share/new',
      data: JSON.stringify({"id": "1", "type": "new", "data": "testabcd"}),
      success:function(response){
       console.log(response);
      }

   });
```

PHP:

```
public function reservation()
{

    $Data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    $data_share = array(
        'id' => $Data['id'],
        'type' => $Data['type'],
        'data' => $Data['data']);

    $this->db->insert('mytable', $data_share);

    return "200";
}
```

Comment: It's better than my code but I still got NULL data when insert to my database. It's mean I still cannot get the data.

Comment: since you were using core js i hv converted to jquery ajax, i think it should work now

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand with converted to jquery ajax. Could you explain more ? Thanks

Comment: i mean the ajax request u send ws not jQuery its core js, which is good but its quite unflexible and tends to break in different browser. i just used the jQuery version of the ajax which is very flexible and cross-browser as well.

Comment: Could you give me some example ?

Comment: please hv a look at this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657287/what-is-the-difference-between-xmlhttprequest-jquery-ajax-jquery-post-jquery
i hop it helps

Comment: After I tried your code I still get NULL. What's the problem ?

Comment: ok what r u getting controller ? try this 

echo '<pre>';print_r($Data);echo '<pre>';exit;

Comment: I just got `<pre></pre>`. Does it means `$Data` is empty ?

Comment: How if I change the method to `GET` not with `POST` ?

Comment: ok den try this ;
`echo file_get_contents('php://input'); exit;` to check weather ur ajax is working or not;

Comment: I got this `id=1&type=new&data=testabcd`

Comment: ok if ur getting dat then try this one to see weather ur getting in post normally.

`echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '<pre>';exit;`

Comment: I got this `<pre>Array()<pre>`

Comment: if just remove ` contentType:'application/json',` and do `'<pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '<pre>';exit;` m sure u will get the data in backend.

Comment: ok got it `JSON.stringify({"id": "1", "type": "new", "data": "testabcd"})` should fix it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147028/discussion-between-riaz-laskar-and-antonio).

Comment: Okay I think we solve the problem. If I change the `method` to `GET` and I receive with `$_GET` the data is receive correctly. Thanks

Comment: your welcome, if it solvers ur ans plz mark it as answer as if anyone else finds the same issue then it will be helpful :)