# Passing HTML and Style Code to PHP using Ajax - Getting 404 server error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tinymce

I trying to send HTML code to php file so i can save into database.

I am getting HTML code from tinyMCE.

I tried all method JSON, encodeURIComponent, encodeURI and escape().

It works perfectly on localhost (on my PC using Wampserver) but not on server (hosted on namecheap).

When i am send simple value like "Hello world" it works perfectly but not full HTML code.

Please check the below code i am using -

```
$('#updatehtml').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    var templatedata =  $('#htmldata').val();
     $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "url to php file",
        data: {template : templatedata},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data){
        alert(data);
        console.log(data);
        }
     });
});
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sevillana" />
<style>
body{background: #ffffff; font-family: Lucida Sans; width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid gray; border-radius: 10px; color: #353333;font-size: 14px;}
p{background: #b3fc7b; border-bottom: 3px #b3fc7b solid; background-repeat: no-repeat; padding: 3em; color: #FFF; clear: left; text-align: center; border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;}
h1{text-shadow: 1px 7px 5px #000;font-family: Sevillana;font-size: 4em;margin:0px;}
h2{width: 89%;margin: 0 auto;padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;font-family: Sevillana;font-size: 2em;color: #FFF; border-radius:10px 0px 10px 0px; background: #b3fc7b;text-shadow: 1px 2px 5px #000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

in PHP

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

ERROR:

```
POST https://www.mywebiste.com/phpfile 404
```

ISSUE RESOLVE after killing myself 3 days -

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623323/handling-json-data-in-codeigniter-controller
```

Comment: 404 means file doesn't exist. Did you write which file you are calling in AJAX? This is wrong `url: "url to php file"`

Comment: When i sent simple value like "Hello world" It gets response without any error.

Comment: `var templatedata =  $('#htmldata').val();` I don't see any element with id `htmldata` in your html file.

Comment: Its getting from tinyMCE <textarea id ="#htmldata"></textarea> Where the HTML code its getting from.

Comment: does `console.log(templatedata);` contail any values? Also maybe the path in your url is wrong so you get a 404 error

Comment: Yes, It shows the full HTML code.

Comment: Then it's probably the path you have in your url field.

Comment: Put the name of a file you are calling to url.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with url  - When i sent simple value like "Hello world" It gets response without any error. only i get error 404 when i am sending HTML code.

Comment: ISSUE RESOLVE after killing myself 3 days -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623323/handling-json-data-in-codeigniter-controller

Answer (score 0):

ISSUE RESOLVE after killing myself 3 days -

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623323/handling-json-data-in-codeigniter-controller
```