# What is Ajax, to be correct, is it only about XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ajax is "asynchronous JavaScript and XML". That is a broad concept. As I understand there are other different systems that do asynchronous JavaScript and XML but not Ajax? And so, as I understand, Ajax only is everything around handling XMLHttpRequest object (or a newer version "fetch API")?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between XMLHttpRequest, jQuery.ajax, jQuery.post, jQuery.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657287/what-is-the-difference-between-xmlhttprequest-jquery-ajax-jquery-post-jquery)

Comment: I looked at those questions and got some picture. Still a question is just about Ajax. I'm studying and want to know practical basics. So as I understand Ajax must be with XMLHttpRequest (or fetch), is that correct? and can be no other implication of ajax w/o it, or?

Comment: yes, you can imagine XMLHttpRequest is the basis, which we build on top of it to create Ajax etc.